# Sql Ordering Hiarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a SQL Statement that I can't seem to figure out.  I need to order the results alphabetically, however, I need "children" to come right after their "parent" in the order.  Below is a simple example of the table and data I'm working with.  All non relevant columns have been removed.  I'm using SQL Server 2005.  Is there an easy way to do this?

```
tblCats
=======

idCat  |  fldCatName        | idParent
--------------------------------------
1      |  Some Category     | null
2      |  A Category        | null
3      |  Top Category      | null
4      |  A Sub Cat         | 1
5      |  Sub Cat1          | 1
6      |  Another Cat       | 2
7      |  Last Cat          | 3
8      |  Sub Sub Cat       | 5


Results of Sql Statement:

A Category
 Another Cat
Some Category
 A Sub Cat1
 Sub Cat 1
  Sub Sub Cat
Top Category
 Last Cat
```

(The prefixed spaces in the result are just to add in understanding of the results, I don't want the prefixed spaces in my sql result.  The result only needs to be in this order.)

Comment: This is something i've wanted to be able to do for a while, especially using CTE recursion, but i've never managed it, i'm interested to see if theres a response.

Comment: I think you have 'A Category' and 'Some Category' reversed in the results

Comment: yeah, i did actually.  I caught that and fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a hierarchical query, as below.

It looks a lot more complicated than it is, due to the lack of a PAD funciton in t-sql. The seed of the hierarchy are the categories without parents. The fourth column we select is their ranking alphabetically (converted to a string and padded). Then we union this with their children. At each recursion, the children will all be at the same level, so we can get their ranking alphabetically without needing to partition. We can concatenate these rankings together down the tree, and order by that.

```
;WITH Hierarchy AS (
    SELECT 
        idCat, fldCatName, idParent, 
        CAST(RIGHT('00000'+ 
                   CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY fldCatName) AS varchar(8))
                   , 5) 
            AS varchar(256)) AS strPath
    FROM Category
    WHERE idParent IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c.idCat, c.fldCatName, c.idParent, 
        CAST(h.strPath + 
            CAST(RIGHT('00000'+ 
                          CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.fldCatName) AS varchar(8))
                       , 5) AS varchar(16)) 
            AS varchar(256))
    FROM Hierarchy h
        INNER JOIN Category c ON c.idParent = h.idCat
)
SELECT idCat, fldCatName, idParent, strPath
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY strPath
```

With your data:

```
idCat  fldCatName      idParent   strPath
------------------------------------------------
  2    A Category        NULL     00001
  6    Another Category  2        0000100001
  1    Some Category     NULL     00002
  4    A Sub Category    1        0000200001
  5    Sub Cat1          1        0000200002
  8    Sub Sub Category  5        000020000200001
  3    Top Category      NULL     00003
  7    Last Category     3        0000300001
```

Comment: just tested it, it works!  thank you.. The query takes a little long, but that would be expected with recursion.

Comment: Yes, it would do I'm afraid. The string manipulation won't help either.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in CTE... Is this what you're after ?

```
   With MyCats (CatName, CatId, CatLevel, SortValue)
   As
    ( Select fldCatName CatName, idCat CatId,
         0 Level, Cast(fldCatName As varChar(200)) SortValue
      From tblCats
      Where idParent Is Null
      Union All
      Select c.fldCatName CatName, c.idCat CatID,
         CatLevel + 1 CatLevel,
         Cast(SortValue + '\' + fldCatName as varChar(200)) SortValue
      From tblCats c Join MyCats p 
          On p.idCat = c.idParent)

   Select CatName, CatId, CatLevel, SortValue
   From MyCats
   Order By SortValue
```

EDIT: (thx to Pauls' comment below)
  If 200 characters is not enough to hold the longest concatenated string "path", then change the value to as high as is needed... you can make it as high as 8000

Comment: That's a nice solution...would be faster to run than mine. You'd need to be careful that the hierarchy didn't reach the depth where the concatenated field names were longer than 200 characters though.

Comment: Yours is just creating abstract strings to represent the names at each level... They will be shorter strings, but why would your solution be any slower ?

Comment: I thought the extra CASTing would slow it down a little, but thinking about it, it probably wouldn't make that much difference in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any SQL Server (or Ansi-SQL) inherent support for this.

I don't supposed you'd consider a temp table and recursive stored procedure an "easy" way ? J

Comment: that does give me some idea, I'll work it out tonight.  I actually figured out a solution by manipulating the data on the code side in the DAL.  I get the entire set and build a hash table using a padded key that is based off the parents, then I sort the keys.  It's a bit inefficient, but it's only a couple hundred records.

Comment: The recursive WITH clause is the ANSI way of handling hierarchical queries.

Comment: May I just say - 
All these subquerying solutions around here are no different than creating an in-memory temp table performance-wise. It's all fine and dandy, but IMHO when you get to a point where you need write recursive SQL statements, you may want to move all that logic into your application code. Depending on your scenario, there's a good chance you won't be missing out on the performance side, and I guarantee your code will be clearer, more readable and easier to understand, plus your fellow programmers and successors will be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer is excellent, but I thought I would throw in another idea for you. Joe Celko has a solution for this in his SQL for Smarties book (chapter 29). It involves maintaining a separate table containing the hierarchy info. Inserts, updates, and deletes are a little complicated, but selects are very fast.

Sorry I don't have a link or any code to post, but if you have access to this book, you may find this helpful.